# How to take 38mp photo on Lumia 1020

Tags: camera, nokia-lumia-1020

My Lumia 1020 is not taking pictures of the highest resolution - it's just taking pictures of approximately 5 MP. How do I take a 38mp photo on Lumia 1020?

Comment: Which camera app are you using?

Comment: Consider making the second part a separate question as it does not directly relate to the first part.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify in your camera settings to capture a 5MP + 38MP image, as @Thomas says, by going into your camera app, and setting the "Camera Mode" option to `JPEG (5MP) + DNG (34MP)`. This takes two images: a 5MP version that is shown to you on the phone, and is what is uploaded to Onedrive if you have that option enabled, and a 38MP version that is hidden.

In order to access the higher-resolution version, you need to connect it to your computer, click on the phone icon, and then go to `Phone > Pictures > Camera Roll`. Your high-resolution versions are suffixed with `__highres`.

As for an introduction to the camera features, the [user guide](http://download.support.nokia.com/ncss/PUBLIC/en_US/webpdf/100000183175/Nokia_Lumia_1020_UG_en_US.pdf) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

In the Lumia Camera app (formerly known as Nokia Camera) you can set the resolution it the settings menu. (Screenshot taken with Lumia 930)

[image]